# How do I ‘expand’ a control sequence `\let` to a character?

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

Consider the following:

```
\let\1=X
\edef\2{\1}
\show\1 \show\2
```

The result is

```
> \1=the letter X.

> \2=macro:
->\1.
```

Is it possible to ‘expand’ the meaning of `\1` so that `\2` contains just `X`? The only solution I can think of is to use `\meaning` on `\1` and cut out the prefix, but that doesn't seem very elegant.

(Context: I'm writing a scanning function that looks ahead at the next token and then either adds it to a scratch variable or terminates the scanning. Can't add it to the scratch variable without expanding it first, though! But it's not the context that I care about, since I can do the loop in another way; I'm interested in this particular question.)

Comment: Maybe we should ask Taco to add such a function to the `token` library.

Comment: Please make this site more user friendly! I wanted to comment (actually ask a question) on Joseph's answer, but I couldn't.

Comment: @Pluto: Welcome to TeX.SX!  This site limits what you can do by how much reputation you have, [as explained in the FAQ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).  To leave comments, you need to get 50 reputation.  If you have questions about how this site works, please ask [over on meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/), and use answers just for something which answers the question.  (Deleting this one would probably be a good idea.)  I hope you stick around here :)

Comment: @Pluto: I think Antal S-Z forgot to mention the most important point: If you've got a question, don't ask it in a comment. Please ask a new question, using "Ask Question", and link to this one if you need to refer to it.

Comment: @Antal: Before you welcome a user to our site, have a look at his user profile. _He_ could have welcomed _you_!

Comment: @Antal: As a new user, he cannot post on meta. I think it's a pretty silly restriction. Can't comment, can't post on meta to complain that he can't comment. _sigh_

Comment: @Pluto: Just a note to confirm Antal and Hendrik's comments, if you have a question then ask a fresh question; this gives you the best chance of it being answered.  You can link back to this one if it is a follow-up question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't expand a token which has been defined using `\let` (unless of course we are taking about something `\let` to another macro). As you say, `\meaning` is the only way that is going to work. Sorry if this is something of a non-answer!

Comment: Yeah, hence my use of the word expand in quotes. I suspected this might be the case, though! Cheers :-)