# How to parse a macro that contains a \let?

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

My situation is similar to, but hopefully different from [How do I ‘expand’ a control sequence `\let` to a character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-do-i-expand-a-control-sequence-let-to-a-character/57583#57583), as that question does not admit a positive answer. I want to parse, not expand, but not character by character, if I can avoid that (as in [Parsing a macro argument character-by-character for conditional execution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33197/parsing-a-macro-argument-character-by-character-for-conditional-execution)). Existing parsers like [Can one define an expandable command that removes control sequences from its argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34029/can-one-define-an-expandable-command-that-removes-control-sequences-from-its-arg) seem not not work for me, unfortunately  (well, I can't get them to work, that is).

Consider the following: There is this `\let` definition

```
\newif\ifintheway
\inthewayfalse
\show\inthewayfalse % ->\let \ifintheway \iffalse .
```

that sits in a macro `\parseme` of which I want to extract the text `17`

```
\def\parseme{\inthewayfalse 17}
```

How can I do that?

Obviously, expanding the macro with `\edef\parsedmacro{\parseme}` does not work and I get the complaint

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 5.
```

However, adding a `\fi` in the `\edef` does not help, either. Is there something else I can do?

In my situation I even know what the obstacle is. It is always `\intheway`. Then there is my text (of which I know it is a number), and then the macro ends. Finally, as an additional obstacle, `\parseme` is really a `\csname b\@citeb\endcsname.

(A positive answer would also resolve [Custom \thebibliography with alphabetic numbering for scrltt2 not working in presence of babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213453/custom-thebibliography-with-alphabetic-numbering-for-scrltt2-not-working-in-pre), at least in parts.)

Comment: Why can't you use `\def` rather than `\edef`?

Comment: @cfr I want to use the content of the macro and the idea with `\edef` was that it expands away the stuff I don't need. In contrast, `\def` does not expand anything, so the obstructing `\let`/`\inthewayfalse` stays where it is and I just have a new macro with a different name but the same problem as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An explicit number can be expanded without changing it and the unwanted
command sequence can be redefined to vanish itself, when expanded:

```
% Setup
\makeatletter
\newif\ifintheway
\def\@citeb{foobar}
\def\bfoobar{\inthewayfalse 17}

% Extract the number from \csname b\@citeb\endcsname
% and store it in the macro \mynumber    
\begingroup
  \let\inthewayfalse\@empty
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \def\noexpand\mynumber{%
      \csname b\@citeb\endcsname
    }%
  }%
\x

% Show the result in the console:
\typeout{My number is "\mynumber".}
\stop
```

The essential part is:

```
\let\inthewayfalse\@empty
% same as:
\def\inthewayfalse{}
% or
\newcommand*{\inthewayfalse}{}
```

And the expansion gets rid of `\intheway`:

```
\edef\mynumber{\csname b\@citeb\endcsname}
```

The example puts this in a group to keep the redefinition
of `\inthewayfalse` local.

Comment: Thanks, that work's for me! I appreciate the explanation, it makes all very clear to me now.